# Google Spreadsheets Function Currying / Aliases

Tags: google-sheets

I have a function that is repeatedly called with (almost) the same parameters, but the only thing that changes is the data range.

How can I curry/alias this function so I would only need to do `func(range)` instead of `func(range, arg1, arg2, arg3...)`?

(My particular function is `query()`, where the range stays the same but the condition is static)

Comment: Not all the functions work on the same way (some require range while others allow range/values/arrays). Please be more specific by including a specific function.

Comment: @Rubén A generic way would be best, but in my case it's `query()`.

Comment: I'm sorry but asking for a generic way make this question too broad. Please add the referred function to the question. Also include an example of the arguments.

Comment: @Rubén I've updated the question with my specific use case.

Comment: @anonymousrabbit Two data ranges, same condition. The columns match. (I got around this by using a cache sheet, therefore using much less `query` than I would need to, but I'm keeping this question open.)

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to do this with QUERY as it requires that its first argument be an array that usually has several rows and columns. The other arguments should be escalar values, references to single cells or formulas that return single values.

Using a reference to 1 X 2 (1 row, two column) range as a way to pass the second and third argument and putting QUERY inside ARRAYFORMULA doesn't work, QUERY ignores it (`=ArrayFormula(QUERY(A1:B4,C1:D1))`)

Answer (score 1):

> have a function that is repeatedly called with (almost) the same parameters, but the only thing that changes is the data range.

Depending on the circumstances,

- You could hard code the arguments inside a custom formula using `Google-apps-script`
- You could use `ARRAYFORMULA`

Based on another generic edit,

> My particular function is `query`

```
=QUERY({A1:B4},Z1,1)
```

Here, `Z1` will contain the arguments, which are static.
Because of the way `query` works, `Z1` just needs to be a compatible text with arguments.

Say, `Z1`:

```
Select Col1, Where Col2 is not null
```

Or

`Z1`:

```
="Select Col1 where Col2 = ' "&A1&" ' "
```